# Block diagonazling an 8by8 matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I have an 8by 8 matrix and I want to transform it to a block diagonalized matrix which each block is a 4 by 4 matrix.

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
    m_0 +J_H & 0 & V & 0 & 0 & \Delta_t & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -m_0-J_H & 0 & V & -\Delta_t & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    V & 0 & -m_0+J_H & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\Delta_t \\
    0 & V & 0 & m_0-J_H & 0 & 0 & \Delta_t & 0\\
    0 & -\Delta_t & 0 & 0 & -m_0-J_H & 0 & -V & 0 \\
    \Delta_t & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & m_0+J_H & 0 & -V \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \Delta_t & -V & 0 & m_0 - J_H & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & -\Delta_t & 0 & 0 & -V & 0 & -m_0+J_H \\
\end{bmatrix} $$

Do you have any idea how I can take those delta terms to the diagonal blocks?! (I don't want to calculate eigenvalues)

Comment: Did you try to simply sort the columns and rows, i.e., apply a permutation matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the orthogonal matrix $$P = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0& 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0& 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1& 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0& 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0& 0& 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0& 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 1& 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
from both sides, i.e., calculate
$$ P A P^T$$
with $A$ your matrix.

Comment: Can you explain how did you get that?

Comment: Just see which rows/columns are coupled to which and think about a rearrangement of the basis vectors that would make two sets of them uncoupled.

Comment: Can you also help me with this one ?! wanna make it 2by2
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
    m_0 +J_H & V & \Delta_t & 0 \\
    V& J_H-m_0 & 0 & -\Delta_t \\ 
    \Delta_t & 0 & J_H+m_0& -V \\
    0 & -\Delta_t & -V & J_H-m_0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$